# Find And Return First Instance of .Text Data Type in Specified Worksheet Row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a specific row and assign to a variable the first instance of a text string contained in that row. The string could be any text string; it just needs to be of data type .text. I tried this:

```
dim firstText as string
dim rowNum as integer

firstText = sheets("Sheet1").Rows(rowNum).Find(What:=Format(vbString))
```

For example, if the row contained: 123, "apple", "pear" and -456, then the function would return the first text string encountered, in this case, "apple"

Alternate method using loop:

```
dim firstText as string
dim rowNum as integer
dim i as integer
const stopCol = 100

For i = 1 To stopCol
    If VarType(Cells(rowNum, i)) = vbString Then
        firstText = Cells(rowNum, i)
        GoTo TheEnd
    End If
Next

TheEnd:
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: the problem with searching on the format is that it requires the cell to *actually be formatted as text**, which could be misleading either way. You may need to loop through the dataset and do a test on each cell and then return the first one that passes (or fails) the test (depending on the test).

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, tried [my interpretation of] your alternative method above. still doesn't work.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, your general advice to use a loop was good advice, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Scott's comment to your question; checking to see if a cell is formatted as text is quite possibly not want you want, as you can type in "=5" to a cell, and click format as text - you can also type "="Hello"" and format as a number.

Perhaps instead, you want to check to see whether the value of a particular cell is actually numeric, like so:

```
Sub duplicateSheets()

    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim testCell As Range
    Dim firstText As String

    rowNum = 10
    Set searchRange = Intersect(Sheets(2).UsedRange, Sheets(2).Range(rowNum & ":" & rowNum))

    For Each testCell In searchRange
        If Not (IsNumeric(testCell.Value)) Then
            firstText = testCell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This is basically what you have above (with a different method of determining the range and looping), but instead of checking the formatting type of the cell, it checks whether the data *within* the cell passes as a number. It picks up the value of the first cell which does *not* pass as a number.

Comment: @Bacon, works, thanks. My version does not work because of the vbString implementation, but does work when I use your IsNumeric suggestion instead.

Comment: that's not what has been asked. use this : `ìf testcell.numberformat="@" then`, wich means if formated as text, look at microsoft help of numberformat.

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier Hi Patrick - I understand that that wasn't what was asked, but in my opinion, the OP would be better served to check what is actually inside the cell, rather than what it is formatted as [as indicated in my answer]. For example, a user might select the whole workbook and say 'format as accounting' (I often do that myself, to avoid selecting each block of numeric cells individually). This would make text values in cells appear formatted as numbers, which is likely (but not 100%) not what the OP wants.